# Microsoft Word macro to sort sections by their title

Tags: macros, ms-word

I've been asked to sort the sections of a very long Word file according to their title.

Is there any easy way to do it using a macro?
If it is not possible, what approach would you go for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word actually already have built-in functionality for this. Doing a quick Google search gave the following tutorial to accomplish what you are asking: http://wordribbon.tips.net/T011238_Sorting_by_Headings.html

I just followed the tutorial using Microsoft Office 2013 without any issues, so hopefully this will get you going :)